# Routing Error: No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, routes

I'm using devise for user authentication. In my views I've set:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li><%= link_to "Log Out",  destroy_user_session_path  %></li>
<% else %>
  <li><%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path  %></li>
<% end %>
```

However when I click Log_Out I'm getting an error:

**No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"**

However when I check my rake routes I'm getting:

```
 devise/sessions#destroy   destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)
```

Comment: `DELETE` has a real meaning, basically its not `GET`

Comment: But I've used the correct syntax for logging out users

Comment: @Mutuma Don't forget to accept the answer which helped you resolve your issue.

Comment: @Kim Already done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What apneadiving said.

```
<%= link_to "Log Out",  destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete  %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Default sign out is use "delete" method. Your route also said the method is “DELETE"

If you want use "get" method

Modify devise.rb to

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

Comment: I figured I didn't add the delete method at the end but I've just corrected the error

Answer (score 0):

Baloo is right, make sure to use the :delete method. You can see this clearly if you invoke

```
rake routes
```

You'll see the path as well as the method.

Comment: Followed his instruction and I found out I had just not included the method at the end